# Error : "Unable to copy file" with content file in nuget package

Tags: web-applications, msbuild, nuget

I'm bulding a legacy web application with msbuild of **"Visual Studio Build Tools 2017"** version 15.9.12. This web application reference a NuGet package (**PackageReference** is used) which include an image as content file.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Resources\Image.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Here the part of **Nuspec file** generated in the package:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        ...
        <dependencies>
            ...
        </dependencies>
        <frameworkAssemblies>
            ...
        </frameworkAssemblies>
        <contentFiles>
            <files include="any/net471/Resources/Image.png" buildAction="Content" />
            <files include="any/net471/Resources/Image.png" buildAction="Content" />
        </contentFiles>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

Strangely the image appears twice in `contentFiles`, but it's not a problem.

The build fails with the error :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5):
>   error MSB3021: Unable to copy file
>   "C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\mypackage\1.0.0-release-anycpu\contentFiles\any\net471\Resources\Image.png"
>   to
>   "C:\Builds\Binaries\_PublishedWebsites\WebApplication.NET471\C:\Users\user.nuget\packages\mypackage\1.0.0-release-anycpu\contentFiles\any\net471\Resources\Image.png".
>   The given path's format is not supported.

Note the double `c:\` in the output path.
When I build from VisualStudio there i no error but the file is not in the ouput directory

Comment: maybe you should report this as a bug at https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues

Comment: The same issue. How you fixed it?

Comment: No solution found. You can comment the issue [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8167)